# At what point did noblemen stop being the backbone of the military?

Tags: middle-ages, war, nobility, modern

During the Dark Ages one of the primary responsibilities of noblemen was to engage in warfare. It was a large part of their education, and a nobleman was expected to be able to win easily against a commoner in a sword fight.

Nowadays noblemen are not fighters. You do not expect Sir Paul McCartney to do well in a fight.

So in what period of history did noblemen actually stop being expected to be directly involved in military conflict?

Comment: Your example isn't a good one, Sir Paul McCartney is not a nobleman.

Comment: There's a number of assumptions in this question that I would want references for: "first and foremost fighters" - I assume you're alluding to the feudal system which required a noble to provide military support. Did that always imply personal involvement or could it be a matter of levies? As for nobles not being fighters anymore: prince Harry and his granddad (one served in Afghanistan, one in WW2, though probably not in hand-to-hand swordfighting) would disagree.

Comment: Noblemen of what region?

Comment: The question is flawed in more ways than one, but the "expected" answer is of course: As soon as peasants could be trained to be (cheaper, more readily available) military forces without actually having to put them through formal, organised training. You make it obligatory for each peasant to own a longbow and practice shooting with it, you get a very cheap fighting force that is capable of holding its own against knights on horseback. Ref. [Agincourt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Agincourt).

Comment: Sir Paul could certainly win a battle of the bands.

Comment: Even long after noblemen stopped being able to win a commoner in hand-to-hand combat, they still were the only class of people able to command large units; both by their formation (and lack of formation of the common people), their pertenence to the stablishment (less risk of a revolution or military coup), the society (common people were already used to obey anything a noble would command, even outside the military) and their interest (being one of the main ways to advance into the upper levels of nobility). Do you want to include that period too?

Comment: Around the time when untrained troops could dominate professional warriors, and command skills outweighed combat skills.  Those developments are tied to the emergence of crossbows and gunpowder weapons.  It is instructive to examine the similar change in Chinese history - when mass peasant levies could overwhelm aristocratic swordsmen.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: "The invention of crossbow and blackpowder put an end to the knight" is common, but falls short of the truth -- it dit put an end to the plate-armored guy on horseback, yes, but the crossbow was "invented" about 400 B.C.; moreover, the bow remained a competitive ranged weapon for quite some while after the invention of gunpowder. It's more about how those weapons and the corresponding troops were employed; the end of the "honorable combat" era. Insofar I absolutely agree with your *first* sentence, if not the rest. ;-)

Comment: Tried to clean it up a little.

Comment: I do remember reading a book that even in the mid-1930s, Royal Navy roll calls still sounded like reading of a list of personages in a royal court.

Answer (score 1):

Nobles were required to provide troops and arms, and be skilled in their command and supply - this was far more important than their combat abilities, and why noblemen had so much power, wealth and prestige.

What happened was the emergence of the modern standing army in the fifteenth century, notably the Ottoman Janissaries and the unorthodox army led by commoners in the service of Charles VII (including one Jean d'Arc and [La Hire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Hire).) Before then, in between conflicts, the nobles would return to the running of their estates, their troops dispersed back to their ordinary life. A standing army never disperses, but trains full time and is ready whenever the monarch desires to go to war.

This lead to the creation of the Spanish [Tericos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tercio) in the sixteenth century - a professional standing army in the service of the Spanish Habsburg empire, commanded by veteran soldiers loyal to the King rather than to the Nobility. They were so successful, the model was eagerly adopted throughout Europe, ending the time where monarchs depended upon their nobility to provide martial muscle. The trend would continue and intensify as the old feudal system began to give way to the modern nation-state - the monarchies in Europe gaining more absolute power and greater wealth to afford mercenaries and royal armies. By the time of the 30 Years War in the mid-17th century, it was almost entirely fought by standing armies rather than feudal levies.

Answer (score 1):

In England the the Parliamentarians' [New Model Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Model_Army) of 1645 was arguably the first state army, not controlled by the monarch or nobility. It comprised mainly professional full-time soldiers rather than a casual militia.

Comment: Men of the upper classes still often follow a standard career path which involves military service. The British Royal Family still feel themselves obliged to join up. So the 'Nobility' might not form the backbone of the British Army; but the officer class still has a dispropotionate number of upper class recruits.